# Is it possible to set a background image with react-canvas-draw?

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I want to implement a background image on my canvas and draw on top of that. I'm using react.js and the package react-canvas-draw.

Comment: it's better to show what you have tried so far, some code snippets, otherwise, it can be impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save reference to your `CanvasDraw` element:

```
<CanvasDraw
  ref={canvasDraw => (this.canvas = canvasDraw)}
/>
```

then, somewhere in the code draw an image using that reference:

```
this.canvas.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
```

Note that [`ctx` is not public api](https://github.com/mBeierl/react-canvas-draw/blob/master/src/index.js), so it's hack-ish. 
`drawImage` is a standard method of CanvasRenderingContext2D: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage